# Как поменять цвет полосы прокрутки JavaFx?

Tags: css, javafx

Как поменять цвет полосы прокрутки в javaFx, `scrollPane.setStyle("-fx-background-color: #131313");`
не помогает, мне нужно изменить цвет ползунка и цвет самой полосы по которой ползунок "ходит".

Comment: Как-то так: https://farrukhobaid.wordpress.com/2013/01/16/dark-scrollbar-skin-for-javafx/

Comment: Может помочь еще: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48048943/javafx-8-scroll-bar-css/48050208